# Gtkmm3 : wait for css transition to finish

Tags: c++, css, gtkmm3

My question does not concern JavaScript, but C++ :

In gtkmm3, application appearance is managed by CSS, so transitions can be set like that :

*theme.css :*

```
.purple {
transition: 500ms linear;
background-image: -gtk-gradient (radial,
    center center, 0,
    center center, 1,
    from (#FFB2E8),
    to (#80005A));
 }
```

*main.cc :*

```
   // Create and define the StyleContext
   CssProvider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
   CssProvider->load_from_path (Glib::build_filename (UI_DIR, "theme.css"));
   Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> ButtonContext = button->get_style_context ();
   ButtonContext->add_provider (CssProvider,
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
   // Assign new color
   ButtonContext->add_class ("purple");
   // Assign an intermediate color
   ButtonContext->remove_class ("purple");
   ButtonContexy->add_class ("green");
   // To something
   // ... ...
   // Change the color again
   ButtonContext->remove_class ("green");
   ButtonContext->add_class ("yellow")
```

With this code, the user sees only the "yellow" state of the button, and not the previous ones, because transitions are skipped.
How to display all the color changes one after the other?

**EDIT :**

My application is a game, where buttons are colored accordingly to their label. This label can change multiple times very closely, and I want the user to see these changes, so, to see the transitions between each state. So, it is not just a flash (my example was not perfect, if you want the whole code of the application, you can get it [here](https://framadrop.org/r/xoc4jBExD-#65qj7nq2T+rb/cqvfsVkKSyoStGNxE1qm8hDxUdNHYU=)).

**EDIT 2:**

I modified the code above and the following sentences to explain my problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make the button flash purple briefly? If so, you can set a timeout with [`GLib::SignalTimeout`](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1SignalTimeout.html) for the correct amount of time that you want the button to flash for.

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise (your answer does not resolve my problem)

Comment: I think it does. If you set the timeout to, for example, 1050 ms, then you get 500 ms of the transition to purple, a 50 ms purple flash, and 500 ms of the transition back to the original color.

Comment: Again, I don't want the button to flash. I want it to wait until the end of the CSS transition before changing its color. It can be multiple successive color changes, in all cases I want the user to see these successive changes (and not just the last color, as it is for the moment). Glib::SignalTimout is not a solution for my problem (I already tested it).

Comment: I have spent a long time learning how to use it, but finally, I managed to do what I wanted with `Glib::signal_timeout ().connect ()`. Thank you and sorry for how long it tool me to accept your answer !